# How to increase font size in webview?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiwebview, ios7.1

I am not able to increase the font size of webview content. I had tried to increase font-size of content contained by JSON Web-Url.

Comment: post your code. Shortly, you can wrap your data into div and style it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1{

int fontSize = 20; 
NSString *jsString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", fontSize] autorelease];
[webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];


}
```

Comment: it is iOS 7.1 don't use release.